# Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't get / display Nextcloud calendar entrys in gnome-calendar

Tags: calendar, nextcloud

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 and added my personal Nextcloud account to "Online Accounts" in system settings. (Designation could be vary because I use German as system language.)
(Fresh install - 2-3 hours old)

When I added the account I didn't get an error or something else.
My server is displayed in the file manager "nautilus" and I have access.
But when I open the calendar (gnome-calendar), non of my entries show up.
Nothing happens on clicking "resync" (German: "Kalender abgleichen") except the calendar icon becomes a hook (HTML: ✓).
Disable and re-enable the calendar has - as well - no effect.
I tried to add a "Test"-entry in the Nextcloud calendar and this one will displayed.
The entry was create on the server and is visible on my mobile phone.
But now the only entry in my calendar is the "Test"-Entry.
This one is displayed but on the others.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lojw.png)

I have no idea what could be the reason, since there is a connection to the server.  It just doesn't show anything.
When I open the calendar-app in the terminal, I don't get an error.

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution in the mean time?

Comment: Same here, any solution? 
BTW: I have the same issue with Evolution (both OnlineAccount and CalDAV entry in Evolution), where my calendar entries are not shown. Surprisingly Thunderbirds calendar will show my entries, when I add the private CalDAV link in Thunderbird.